# How to have same database state between distributed vagrant boxes?

Tags: database, vagrant

Scenario:
I built original Vagrant box, which got installed to several computers. Git tracks changes to the code, but when someone locally collects data to the database (say mysql), or changes schema, I'd like to somehow automate the task of keeping all vagrant boxes "updated" with database changes.

Same question goes for installing new packages/software locally on vagrant box, and then distributing those changes to other installations. I did this with custom shell script that executes on vagrant up, but it seems like a wrong way to do the same for the database (dump, drop, import).

Can it be done with some provisioning tool? All the google results are pointing to initial building of a box, and provisioning; no luck in finding out how to deal with local changes...

Comment: Have you considered using database migrations as a part of the build process? Something like http://flywaydb.org/ perhaps?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, migrations would take care of updating schema, but not already inserted thousands of records of data, and would have to be wrote manually.

Comment: I think this workflow of inserting thousands of record is wrong. Why dont you reduce them to few rows for each table. Then keep the sql in your private repo. After that you can probably create a script to download the .sql file and run it as part of the setup again.